# Как выводить левый блок только на главной странице,а на всех остальных его скрывать?

Tags: php

Слева блок это категории. На каждой странице (/cart или /register) видно этот блок. Как ограничить его только в maine странице. Можно это как по по url отслеживать ? или еще как то.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это голый `php` - чуть меньше копипаста, если CMS или Framework - нужно знать что используете.

Answer (score 1):

Через `$_SERVER`

1) `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // покажет - /index.php`

или

2) `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // покажет - www.site.ru/`

Дальше через `if` отключите/включите блок

Answer (score 0):

Ты бы поподробнее рассказал что используешь: mvc или cms какую-то
Если mvc, то в контроллере можешь отслеживать url и во вью передавать {visibleFalse}, которую в контроллере при нужном урл определять например

```
    $visibleFalse = "style='display:none;'";
```

А если cms, то нужно знать хотя бы какая.